# How to debug issue with CMake custom command dependencies

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to debug an issue with dependencies in custom commands in CMake. My dependence structure basically looks like (using GraphViz notation):

```
A -> B
{A; B} -> C -> D -> E
```

Where C and E are `add_custom_target`, and A, B and D are `add_custom_command`. CMake correctly infers a target-level dependency between C and E, but on the first build of the project, B does not get built as part of target C. As a result E fails (because it needs B to exist). But on the *second* build, B gets generated as part of C and everything works fine.

At the moment, I don't even know how to debug this, especially in Visual Studio where the project files are fairly opaque. I can see what gets built in any given build, but for the things that aren't getting built, I can't see why they aren't being built. The available debugging methods in CMake (like `--trace`) seem to be useful only for configure-time issues, which this isn't.

Are there any tools for debugging these sorts of things, or do I just have to stare at my CMake file until I figure this out?

For posterity, there are more specific details about my problem below, but I will be happy to debug it myself if I can find any reasonable way to do so: https://github.com/zdevito/terra/pull/322#issuecomment-441084534

Comment: Building is not controlled by CMake, so you unlikely will get help from it. You are better consult Visual Studio, as it actually performs the building. As for the specific case, it seems that `D` and `E` are unrelated for your problem: Have you tried to build just `C` and check whether `B` is built? If `B` is not built in this case, you need to recheck only `B`->`C` dependency in your CMake code.